# Passing ArrayList as IEnumerable to a method

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have an array List as follows;

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    myArrayList.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Then I am using IEnumerator and trying to pass the value to a function.

```
IEnumerator eee = myArrayList.GetEnumerator();
```

Now calling the function.

```
iteratefrom5to10(eee); //The error shown here is some invalid arguments.

static void iteratefrom5to10(IEnumerator<int> ien)
{
    while (ien.MoveNext())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ien.Current.ToString());
    }
}
```

The above approach has worked with List. But not with ArrayList. What is wrong?

Comment: Put the exact error.

Comment: You are trying to match the non-generic `IEnumerator` with the generic `IEnumerator<int>`.

Comment: "What is wrong?" You're using `ArrayList`, you should carry on using `List<T>`, it offers many benefits such as type safety

Comment: This is the error. The best overload method windows form application.Form1.Iteratefrom5to10(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<int>) has some invalid arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `myArrayList` to `IEnumerable<int>` like this:

```
IEnumerator<int> eee = myArrayList.Cast<int>().GetEnumerator();
```

Please note that you are adding strings to the `ArrayList`. You should be adding integers instead like this:

```
ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();

for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
    myArrayList.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to Yacoub Massad. Your answer is perfect for me. Thanks to everyone who came up with their answers too.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
myArrayList.ToArray().AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 3):

Stop using `ArrayList` - there are very few cases where you'd want to use it.

Since you're working with a list of integers, just use `List<int>` instead - no need to convert all the values to string and back :)

Finally, why are you using `GetEnumerator` anyway? Change the argument to `IEnumerable<int>` and the `while` to a `foreach`:

```
var list = new List<int>();

for (var i = 0; i <= 1000; i++)
{
  list.Add(i);
}

static void iteratefrom5to10(IEnumerable<int> ien)
{
  foreach (var value in ien)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
  }
}
```

`IEnumerable`s are very easy to work with. For example, as your method's name suggests you want to iterate from 5 to 10, the same can be done with a simple `list.Skip(4).Take(6)`.

Comment: This is indeed the only right answer. Just to note that IMO passing `IEnumerator<T>` to a method is a very bad idea for both callee and caller, since neither the former (at the beginning) nor the later (after return) knows where enumerator is positioned (i.e. should it call `MoveNext` or not)

Comment: I did not quite follow your comment. Could you please make it more elaborate?